# c# wpf how to preview attachment(word, pdf) not use office online, Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, wpf, attachment

I want to prieview attachment in my wpf application

I cannot user web, I use this application in my local network

I try GemBox.Pdf、spire and aspose, there charge, thank you 3
I want to prieview attachment in my wpf application

I cannot user web, I use this application in my local network

I try GemBox.Pdf、spire and aspose, there charge, thank you 3
f

Comment: You can use Wpf:WebView2 to preview PDF inside of WPF App Window.

Comment: There are free PDF viewers for .NET (I use PDFium with my own interop) but I know of nothing that will make Word or other Office files viewable that doesn't charge. I use Aspose. It is surprisingly good (though definitely not bug-free).

Comment: As an alternative to MSOffice online, OnlyOffice is open-source and provides a [document server](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/basic) that you can self-host.

Comment: @Aenye_Cerbin I want to preview not pdf but also word

Comment: @NPras I can not use an external server, I have to use a local one and I can not use the internet for the wpf

Comment: When I said self-host OnlyOffice, I meant on a machine on your local network.

Comment: It's this one onlyoffice.com/blog/2023/07/self-hosted-onlyoffice-docspace, thank you @NPras

Comment: Could I build my own server as an interactive server for previewing attachments, such as google email to preview mail attachments online

Answer (score 0):

You can render/preview Email attachments (e.g. Word, PDF) using GroupDocs.Viewer for .NET as follows (API allows to render or generate source file previews in [HTML, PDF or Image](https://docs.groupdocs.com/viewer/net/rendering-documents/) formats):

```
// Specify attachment.
Attachment attachment = new Attachment("attachment-word.doc", @"C:\Output\attachment-word.doc"); 
// Create a stream for attachment.
MemoryStream attachmentStream = new MemoryStream();
//Save attachment
using (Viewer viewer = new Viewer("sample.msg"))
{
    viewer.SaveAttachment(attachment, attachmentStream); 
}
// Render attachment
using (Viewer viewer = new Viewer(attachmentStream))
{
    HtmlViewOptions options = HtmlViewOptions.ForEmbeddedResources();
    viewer.View(options);
}
```

API supports [listing and extracting/saving](https://docs.groupdocs.com/viewer/net/working-with-attachments/) attachments as well. It's a stand-alone backend API that can be integrated in your C# WPF application. Please take a look at this open-source console [application](https://github.com/groupdocs-viewer/GroupDocs.Viewer-for-.NET/tree/master/Examples/GroupDocs.Viewer.Examples.CSharp).

PS. I am working as Support developer/Evangelist at GroupDocs.